# My Nvidia GPU isn't detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, additional-drivers

I'm using GTX 460. 
When I use 'Additional Drivers' it says "No additional drivers available."

After running the 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63.run' it gives me the following messages

```
WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 352.63     
           NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For further 
           details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in 
           the README available on the Linux driver download page at           
           www.nvidia.com.

                                   OK
```

Then

```
 ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
         installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
         THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
         download page at www.nvidia.com.

                                       OK
```

And finally

```
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
         '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find            
         suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available   
         on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.

                                       OK
```

When I used `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` I got

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 041e (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8534
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Also when trying `nvidia-detector` I get `none`

If I need to add any information tell me and I'll add asap

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Is there something I don't understand about it or is there another problem?

Comment: Why do you think you have an Nvidia adapter?

Comment: OK, what is GTX 460? It is an Nvidia adapter. It is not seen in the system. You either do not have it, or it is not installed well, or disabled in bios.

Comment: I've checked the adapter multiple times, cleaned the dust out of the slot originally as well, it's locked in place, and the fan is working (although that doesn't say much except for the power).

Comment: @Nate Try checking in your BIOS if the GPU is even being recognized. If it's not recognized by the BIOS then Ubuntu won't recognize it. Sometimes you have to change it so that it uses the discrete graphis instead of the integrated graphics.

Comment: What am I looking for in my BIOS?

Comment: Try looking for GTX 460/Nvidia, ...in my BIOS that is.