# Wrong screen resolution and big black space on the right side of screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, screen, display-resolution

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (it's the first time I'm using Ubuntu) and I've got this common screen resolution issue (stuck at 1024x768(4:3) but my resolution should be 1368x768). In addition, I get this black empty space on the right of my screen.

[image]

I'm not sure there's anything I haven't tried after searching the web for two days now (updated NVIDIA drivers, created and manually set screen resolution in xorg.conf, forced screen resolution using all sorts of xrandr commands...), it's become frustrating. I'm thinking the black empty space issue, given it's uncommon, could be a lead.

Could there be anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you boot from the Ubuntu Live DVD? Did your screen ever look correct, or is this something new? I assume that you've tried setting the resolution in the Displays setting panel, and in the Nvidia software? It should be set to 16:9, not 4:3. Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes, @heynnema, I've tried using the displays setting panel (all resolution options there are below 1024x768). In the Nvidia XServer Settings however, I can't find a means of editing the resolution :( . Just application profiles and settings configuration (which has nothing more than a couple of checkboxes. No way to select display resolution). I run Windows 10 on the same PC and the screen is ok there

Comment: You didn't answer my first question, about what happens if you boot the Ubuntu Live DVD. Also, you said that under Windows 10 "the screen is ok there **too**". **Too** is the key word there... is there any other environment that causes the screen to be correct? Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks, @heynnema :). Tried to disambiguate that by taking off the "too". The resolution is ok on Windows, and I don't see the big black border. Also, it's full screen every time from startup, until I select Ubuntu from the dual booting menu and it starts loading, i.e. the issue only occurs with Ubuntu. I booted the live DVD and tried Ubuntu. Same issue (wrong resolution & big empty space)

Comment: By booting to the Live DVD, and seeing that the problem exists, at least we've eliminated a borked Ubuntu install. I've got to believe that the problem lies with the software for the Nvidia. Are you sure that you've got the correct software installed? I'm no expert on this, but I've seen so much banter about the Nvidia software, that I've got to believe that there's something there. Research that more. Search here at askUbuntu about Nvidia drivers. Cheers, Al

Comment: What model Nvidia do you have? Have you checked for a firmware update for it? Cheers, Al

Comment: I can't say what model I have, however, I tried manually installing some drivers, but each time ran into this error: http://askubuntu.com/questions/710262/my-nvidia-gpu-isnt-detected. Too bad there's no answer to the issue on that thread :(

Comment: Oh, there we go. Nvidia driver install failure. Should have said so earlier. Did you check if your BIOS sees the card? In terminal, type `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` and post the results. What is the name/version of the Nvidia driver you installed? They're going to push us to chat real soon, but the link will be here. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi @heynnema, this is what I got `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03)`  `Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)` `Kernel driver in use: i915`

Comment: I don't see an Nvidia card there. You need to check your BIOS and make sure it can see the card and that it's enabled. If you don't see it, check for a BIOS update from the manufacturer's web site. Do you have your video monitor connected to the Nvidia card, or to the internal video port? I assume that this is a desktop computer, yes? If so, pull the Nvidia and look for a model number, and also check if the computer will display properly without the Nvidia installed. Cheers, Al

Comment: Are you using a **video monitor** or a **TV**? What model is it? In either case, is it connected **directly** to the video port, or does it go through any additional adapters/cables? Cheers, Al

Comment: Actually I'm using a laptop, ASUS F3Eseries. I'm checking the BIOS now. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Go to http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/78/0/17/8/ and make sure you've got the current BIOS 305. Cheers, Al

Comment: Do you have **anything** connected to the VGA port? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

After a lengthy discussion in the comments, it was determined that the Nvidia drivers were not installed correctly. The Nvidia installer did not find his card. The user is uncertain which Nvidia card he has, and until we determine which one he has, we won't know which driver to recommend.

The user may have a Nvidia firmware problem. There's certainly a Nvidia software problem. There may be a system BIOS upgrade needed.

Procedures have been put into the comments for the user to help identify his Nvidia card.

edit: go to http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/78/0/17/8/ and make sure you have BIOS 305 installed.

edit: turns out the user has a ASUS F3E series laptop, and a Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller using the i915 driver, capable of 1280 x 800 ( WXGA ) on the internal screen.